# custom 404 page in subfolder Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-routing

How to create custom 404 page in subfolder Codeigniter?
I tried the following but no avail:

http://tutsnare.com/create-custom-404-page-codeigniter/

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you working with controllers inside a sub-folder? If so, extend the Exceptions class by creating application/core/MY_Exceptions.php

Put the following code:

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions 
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * 404 Page Not Found Handler
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    public function show_404($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
    {

        /**
         * Quick fix for 404 Override bug.
         * 
         * index.php/non-existent-controller                        -----> override ok
         * index.php/existent-controller/non-existent-method        -----> override not ok
         * index.php/existent-folder/non-existent-controller        -----> override not ok
         */

        $router =& load_class('Router', 'core');
        if ( ! empty($router->routes['404_override']))
        {
            if ($log_error) log_message('error', '404 Page Not Found --> '. $page);

            $config =& load_class('Config', 'core');
            header('Location: '. $config->site_url($router->routes['404_override']));
            exit;
        }

        /* End of fix */

        $heading = "404 Page Not Found";
        $message = "The page you requested was not found.";

        // By default we log this, but allow a dev to skip it
        if ($log_error)
        {
            log_message('error', '404 Page Not Found --> '.$page);
        }

        echo $this->show_error($heading, $message, 'error_404', 404);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working. But the URL is changing. It is because of header(). Is there a way to retain the original (broken link) that the user type?

Comment: You could just change the header() to echo file_get_contents($config->site_url($router->routes['404_override']));

Answer (score 0):

You have `$route[‘404_override’] = ‘’;` in you route.php config.
You can set a controller like page_error.php and keep URL so you won’t have a redirect.

```
$route['404_override'] = 'page_error'; 

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class page_error extends CI_Controller
{
 function index()
  {
    $this->output->set_status_header('404');
     echo '404';
   }
} 
?>
```

check [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) for routing

Answer (score 0):

Just see your application/routes.php file `$route['404_override'] = '';`

first change above `$route['404_override'] = '';` to  `$route['404_override'] = 'custom_error';`

go you application/controllers

create new controller with name custom_error

```
class Custom_error extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();



    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo "404 Rajaram Custom Message";
    }

}
```

You need more details about routes visit official web site
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I tried this still have a problem on subfolders.
I noticed that using this option my custom 404 page works:

http://localhost/my-web/testx (OK - No error)

http://localhost/my-web/login/testx (Default 404)